# C++ if end of string has "ed" or "ing"

Tags: c++, nlp

Working on a Natural Language Processor and I've been struggling. I've been trying to make a way, to see if a word that has been parsed, ends with "ed" or "ing" so I can dictate the context of a verb.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Off topic: You are misusing the comma. On topic this is trickier than it looks. The word "bring" for example.

Comment: Consider using a programming language with more built in string functions as well.  Grep support also will make things easier, but can make things run slower if over used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string::compare` to check that a particular suffix exists:

```
bool ends_with(std::string const &str, std::string const& suffix){
    return str.size() >= suffix.size() &&
           str.compare(str.size() - suffix.size(), suffix.size(), suffix) == 0;
}

ends_with(str,"ed");
ends_with(str,"ing");
```

Alternatively, you could use boost algorithms:

```
boost::algorithm::ends_with(str,"ed");
boost::algorithm::ends_with(str,"ing");
```

Natural language processing is more complicated than checking for these suffixes,
but this can be a start.